# Jquery syntax selector element issue

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems with jquery syntax finding the same element but written differently.

```
for (var i = 0; i < _max ; i++) {
var _carouselCell = "<div class=\"carousel-cell\"><div class=\"item 1\" id=\ itm \ " + i + "\"></div></div>";

 $('.main-carousel').append( _carouselCell );

 $('#itm' + i).html('<img class="item-img" src="' + _url + '' + i + '.jpg"><img>');}
```

What's causing me problems is in **var_carouselCell** > **id=\ itm \ " + i + "**
that becomes a selector below **$('#itm' + i)** 
But I realised that my selector syntax doesn't match with this **id=\ itm \ " + i + "**

My aim is just to append that div id= itm**i** and then select it to load an img in it.

Comment: You could just use single quotes instead of double. Then you dont need escaping. Like class=‘carouse’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using double quote at starting of `id`. Try fixing that.

Otherwise

This should solve your purpose, use singleQuote instead of double.

```
var _carouselCell = "<div class= 'carousel-cell'><div class= 'item 1' id='itm " + i +  "'></div></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting quotes in the beginning of ID, this might be the problem. Also this will make it more readable:

```
var _carouselCell =   "<div class='carousel-cell'>"
                    +   "<div class='item 1' id='itm" + i + "'>"
                    +   "</div>"
                    + "</div>";
```

Be careful with the `class="item 1"`. This is applying two distinct classes (`item` and `1`) instead of `item1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Putting quotes solved the problem. 
Didn't know you could writte it that way. It's actually a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what browsers you need to support you could also use String interpolation / Template Literals

browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

```
for (var i = 0; i < _max ; i++) {
    var _carouselCell = `
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="item 1" id="itm${i}" ></div>
        </div>`;

    $('.main-carousel').append( _carouselCell );

    $('#itm' + i).html(`<img class="item-img" src="${_url}${i}.jpg"><img>`);
}
```

Comment: So, correct me if i'm wrong, using String interpolation / Template Literals is better because they can be read by more browsers than without?

Answer (score 0):

Class name shouldn't start with a number. Give `-` or `_` in between `item 1`.

You can use mix of single and double quotes.

```
var _carouselCell = '<div class="carousel-cell"><div class="item_1" id="itm'+i+'">'+i+'</div></div>';
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/x1pLt9cn/9/)